# ActionListener not working with all of the objects

Tags: java, sql, swing, object, jpanel

I have a problem that when I create a scrollpane with panels in them that are objects I want to add a button to every panel that when I click on it it will return the name of the product and put it in a variable. Problem is that it is only the last object panel in the scrollpane that gets connected to the Action Listener. Here is the code for the scrollpane and individual panels:

```
try{
   System.out.println(sql);
   ResultSet rs = data.SQL.executeQuery(sql);
   String list = "";
   int count=0;
   while (rs.next()){
      count++;
   }
   ResultSet result = data.SQL.executeQuery(sql);
   ProductDisplayPanel.removeAll();
   JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
   addPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (count, 1));
   JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

   while (result.next()) {
      searchDisplay  = new SearchDisplay (result);            
      scroll.add(searchDisplay);
      addPanel.add(searchDisplay);

   }    
   scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(425,390));
   scroll.setViewportView(addPanel);
   ProductDisplayPanel.add(scroll);
   ProductDisplayPanel.revalidate();
   ProductDisplayPanel.repaint();
   System.out.println(list);

   SearchDisplay.AddToCart.addActionListener(action);
   frame.add(SearchDisplay.AddToCart);
} catch (Exception ae){
      ae.printStackTrace(); 
  }

} catch (Exception e1) {

  e1.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Class that creates the actual panels:

```
public SearchDisplay(ResultSet result) throws Exception{

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 156));
    setVisible(true);


    String link = result.getString("image");
    System.out.println(link);

    BufferedImage icecream = ImageIO.read( new URL( "file:///"+link));
    JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon (icecream));

    name = result.getString("Name");
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel(name);

    String category = result.getString("Pieces");
    JLabel lblFlavour = new JLabel("Pieces: "+category);

    String productID = result.getString("ProductID");
    JLabel lblPrice = new JLabel("Product ID: " + productID);

    String price = result.getString("Price");
    JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Price: "+ price +" kr");

    String age= result.getString("Age");
    JLabel lblBrand = new JLabel("Age: "+age);



     AddToCart = new JButton("Add to cart");
```

Comment: Don't use `JScrollPane#add`, this is not how you set the scroll pane's view.  Instead use `JScrollPane#setViewportView`. Check out [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details.  Remember, a scroll pane can only have a single view

Comment: All the panels display nicely, that is not the problem. I add a JButton to every panel and a listener to this button. Problem is that it only works for one of the panels and not all when you click on it

Comment: Shame you didn't provide the code that demonstrates how the action listener is registered or works...(also, it's actually a series is little accidents that actually gets the scroll pane to work)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Everything works, it is just that when I click the add to cart button it only works for the last search display object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just not sure how you expected this to work...

You create a series of `SearchDisplay`s and add them to the scroll pane (via the `addPanel`)

```
    while (result.next()) {
        searchDisplay  = new SearchDisplay (result);            
        // nb- Bad idea
        scroll.add(searchDisplay);
        addPanel.add(searchDisplay);
    }    
    // nb- Worrisome...
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(425,390));
    scroll.setViewportView(addPanel);
```

Then you seem to add a single `ActionListener` to the some static object

```
    SearchDisplay.AddToCart.addActionListener(action);
```

What's the connection?  How does this `AddToCart` button know what it should be adding?  Do you set some other `static` variable in the process??

I would imagin that every instance of `SearchDisplay` would have it's own `AddToCart` and it would have it's own `ActionListener` which knew which item it was associated with...

Comment: I have to add the actionlistener after I create the searchdisplay objects or else I will get a null pointer exception

Comment: @GarfieldMcCracker: if you're having a problem with trying his solution, then you will want to show your code attempt, show all error messages, and indicate which line throws the exception. 1+ to this answer.

Comment: @GarfieldMcCracker The problem as I see it is you are adding a "single" action listener that you want applied to a "group" of possible actions.  The problem is, how does the "single" action listener know anything about any of the other items?

Comment: So how exactky do I dynamically add an ActionListener to the other objects?

Comment: Step back for a minute.  It's unlikely that you want to add an `ActionListener` to all your `SearchDisplay`, but instead, want to add a "Cart" reference to them instead.  This way when the `AddToCart` button of the `SearchDisplay` instance is pressed, it can add what ever details it needs to the the "Cart"

Comment: Is there any way to do that without an Action Listener?

Comment: Each `AddToCart` button would need it's own `ActionListener`, which would know what it needs to do to add the item in question to the "Cart"

Comment: So it seems I would have to make some sort of a loop to add the action listeners dynamically each time

Comment: @GarfieldMcCracker The problem I have with that, is how are you going to identify what product was clicked...